# MVC client side validation not working after deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have just deployed my MVC 4 application to IIS 8 on a new Windows Server 2012.

However, MVC client side validation appears to have stopped working. I have checked that the correct .js files have been copied across with the deployment.

My AppSettings in the web.config has:

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Very grateful for any help.

Martin

Comment: could you check in the browser console if all is ok (under Console tab)?

Comment: also, try loading site with fiddler running and make sure you don't see any 404s or error messages in it as it loads everything

Comment: I get the following, which I believe is to do with the version of jQuery I am using. However, I get the same message when running code locally in Visual Studio...and the validation works fine then:                                                               Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live' in jqueryval

Comment: Fiddler: all seems okay too...there is a 404 but it is for a redundant CSS which I am not using anyway. Then I also see a 500 from after the form submission (caused by my validation not stopping the form submission!)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be quite obscure...two Linker Address Map files from my 'Content' folder had not copied across. Also, I updated my version of jQuery to resolve the Uncaught TypeError mentioned above. This has fixed the problem.